# Excel VBA - merge cells if values in columns equals

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a macro to get results as follows:

[image: Excel results - attachment]

I have no idea how to do it. This is what I've done so far.

I want to have additional column "Action" and if value in column "State" for e.g R1 is empty or "no_fix" then QM (green) else QA (red).

I have data with ~5000 rows

[image: Additional conditions]

Hi, thanks it works as I expected. However, after testing of my data it turned out that I need to check additional conditions.

1.Additionally for QM and QA:
check in column G if value = "ST"
check in column H if value = 0

2.QA

> check in column C if value = "No TC for LM"  check in column D if
>   value = "no state" check in column E if value = "No IPIS" if any of
>   values = true then QA

```
    Sub MergeSameCell()
    'area
    Dim Rng As Range, xCell As Range, Test As Range
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim xRows As Integer
    xTitleId = "Merge duplicated cells"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, 
    Type:=8)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    xRows = WorkRng.Rows.Count
    For Each Rng In WorkRng.Columns
    For i = 1 To xRows - 1
        For j = i + 1 To xRows
            'If Rng.Cells(i, 1).Value > 0 And Rng.Cells(j, 1).Value > 0 Then
            If Rng.Cells(i, 1).Value <> Rng.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
                  Exit For
            End If
        Next
        'WorkRng.Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 1), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 1)).Merge
        'Text = WorkRng.Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 1), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 1))
        i = j - 1
        For Each Rng1 In Range(Rng.Cells(i, 1), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 1))
            For Z = 1 To 13
         'MsgBox i
        'MsgBox j
            If Rng1.Offset(Z, 1).Value = "no_to_fix" Or Rng1.Offset(Z, 
        1).Value 
       = "" Then

            'WorkRng.Parent.Range(Rng.Cells(i, 1), Rng.Cells(j - 1, 
         1)).Merge
            Rng1.Cells.Offset(Z, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
            'MsgBox "supcio"
            End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
    Next
    WorkRng.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: I think you forgot to post your code after the sentence "This is what I've done so far."  (And, if you limit the question to one issue only - e.g. "How do I merge cells in one column if the values in another column are equal?" - then your question is less likely to be closed as being "Too broad".  After that issue gets answered, raise another question about how to write an `If` statement.)

Comment: Hi, you're right :) I forgot to put my code. Thanks!

Comment: Generally, I need to get input as shown in attachment. I've change so many times my code, and it didn't work anyway. Maybe it might be done in different way. I spent a whole weekend and now I'm blocked how to handle it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will do the merging you want and, if I understand what you mean by the second part of the question, will set the first column to be either "QM" (if the fourth column is never anything other than blank or "no_fix") or "QA".

Code assumes you will use the `InputBox` to select a range containing four columns, the first being the column that will contain "QM" or "QA", the second being the column that is your "Req" column, and the fourth being your "State" column.  (The code never looks at what is in the third column.)

```
Sub MergeSameCell()
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    xTitleId = "Merge duplicated cells"
    Set WorkRng = Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim isQM As Boolean
    'Use "startRow" to keep track of the start of each block
    startRow = 1
    With WorkRng
        'Loop through each row in the selected range
        For endRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
            If .Cells(endRow + 1, 2).Value <> .Cells(startRow, 2).Value Then
                'Only do something if the next row has a different value in the second column

                'merge rows in the first and second columns
                .Worksheet.Range(.Cells(startRow, 1), .Cells(endRow, 1)).MergeCells = True
                .Worksheet.Range(.Cells(startRow, 2), .Cells(endRow, 2)).MergeCells = True

                'Check for "no_fix" or blank
                isQM = True  ' Assume it is a "QM" until we determine it isn't
                For r = startRow To endRow
                    If .Cells(r, 4).Value <> "" And .Cells(r, 4).Value <> "no_fix" Then
                        'If the 4th column is not blank and is not "no_fix", it isn't a "QM"
                        isQM = False
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next

                'Update column 1 to show QM or QA
                With .Cells(startRow, 1)
                    If isQM Then
                        .Value = "QM"
                        .Interior.Color = vbGreen
                    Else
                        .Value = "QA"
                        .Interior.Color = vbRed
                    End If
                End With

                'Point to start of next block
                startRow = endRow + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks it works as I expected. However, after testing my data it turned out that I need to check additional conditions.

check in column C if value = "No TC for LM" 
check in column D if value = "no state"
check in column D if value = "No IPIS"

Comment: @MaciejJ You should really raise a new question for the new issue.  Setting a value based on information in other columns really has nothing to do with "merge cells if values in columns equals".  Stack Overflow questions really are of no use if they deal with multiple issues.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. You really helped me with your solution. I will raise a new issue.